Reactive Search & cluster on Elasti.co > Difficulty to connect to the cluster
I use this doc : https://docs.reactivesearch.io/docs/reactivesearch/react/overview/quickstart/, and tried to connect the reactive search with my hosted cluster in Elasti.co.
If I use the cluster specified in the documentation (https://appbase-demo-ansible-abxiydt-arc.searchbase.io), the search is working fine.
If I configure my cluster (Elasti.co) I cannot connect, and the searchbox returns a 400 error.
CORS data is set up correctly on Elasti.co (elasticsearch.yml).
Should I specify a port on the 'URL' prop? (9200?) I tried this, I no longer have an error loading the search but no data is received.
Here is my component :
    <ReactiveBase
  url="https://xxxxxxx.aws.elastic-cloud.com"
  app="my_index"
  credentials="username:password"
>

Do you have any tips or default settings to recommend? My cluster is running on ES 8.
Thanks for your help.

You want to connect directly from the front-end to the database ? Are you sure ? Your users will be able to get the credentials to your database.

If a set an URL prop without :port, i get this error : https://xxxxx.elastic-cloud.com/my_index/_reactivesearch 400 (Bad Request)...

@Paulo, for the moment, and as the documentation explains, I define the URL prop with the credentials. Do you know another connection method for reactive search? Proxy?
